# How to obtain current isolation level on DB2?

Tags: transactions, db2, ibm-midrange, isolation-level

I am trying to learn how transactions work in DB and to do this I wrote the following test SQL:

```
SAVEPOINT STOP_HERE ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;

INSERT INTO TESTSCHEMA."test" (ID, NAME) VALUES (89898, 'SDFASDFASD');

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT STOP_HERE;

SELECT * FROM TESTSCHEMA."test";
```

After execution of this code the one row is added into the table. But if I add the following line at the beginning:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

all work as I expected, i.e. transaction correctly rolled back and no new entries in DB, but if I run this code again the Data Studio shows me error in the first line:

```
[SQL0428] SQL statement can not be launched.
```

So my questions are:
Is there a way to obtain current isolation level and why I can't set isolation level more than 1 time?

I would be very thankful for all answers and links.

PS. I am using DB2/iSeries V5R4.

PPS. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you doing SQL COMMIT's after each of your set statements?

Comment: No, just SQL that I posted in body of question

Comment: For your driver, try [getDefaultTransactionIsolation()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fas400%2Faccess%2FAS400JDBCDatabaseMetaData.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get the current isolation level from special register [current isolation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010945.html). You get the [SQL0428](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00428n.html) because you didn't COMMIT or ROLLBACK before setting the isolation level, and there were transactions still in process in that session.

Comment: I don't have special register CURRENT ISOLATION in my version of DB2 http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp Do you another way to obtain current isolation level?

Comment: @Andriy Petrivskyy I do not believe there is... Most often you would use some application server and frameworks that would keep track of those things for you...

Comment: You are right. Driver that I have to use (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fas400%2Faccess%2Fdoc-files%2FJDBCProperties.html) really have option to set isolation level. Thank you.

Comment: Please forgive me @erloewe, but I notice you have knowledge of DB2 isolation levels, if you know the answer to this question I would much appreciate tapping into your knowledge:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276571/allow-dirty-reads-in-db2-using-ado-net