# Is rollback can work without savepoints in DB2?

Tags: transactions, db2, rollback, ibm-midrange, unit-of-work

This question partially related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946986/how-to-obtain-current-isolation-level-on-db2)

Why my transaction is not rolled back when using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TESTSCHEMA."test" (ID, NAME) VALUES (11111, 'SDFASDFASD');

ROLLBACK;
```

As I known from the DB2/iSeries documentation:

> The ROLLBACK statement is used to end a unit of work and to back out the database changes that were made by that unit of work.

What is an indicator that unit of work started or ended? What will be rolled back in example mentioned above?

I would be very thankful for all answers and links.

PS. I am using DB2/iSeries V5R4.

PPS. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Try adding a custom parameter autocommit=false into the connection parameters or url?

Comment: Driver that I have to use don't have option autocommit(http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fas400%2Faccess%2Fdoc-files%2FJDBCProperties.html) but I tried to use option you mentioned without any success :-(. In any case, thank you for your help.

Comment: It depends on the "transaction isolation" setting which you set for the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in DB2 is done within a the scope of a transaction.  A transaction ends on COMMIT (either explicit or implicit) or ROLLBACK.

Keep in mind that, by default, many clients have the autoCommit parameter set to true, which means that after every statement there is an implicit COMMIT.

So, in your example above, I'm going to assume that autoCommit was on, and the INSERT was committed immediately.  Thus, the ROLLBACK statement did nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How I can check using SQL if auto-commit mode is on? I investigated that auto-commit can be disabled from JDBC, but is it possible to disable it using SQL for the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [iSeries Commitment Control topic for v5r4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakj%2Frzakjcommitkickoff.htm).

Here's the [IBM Toolbox for Java Commitment Control topic for v5r4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Frlacmt.htm).