# How to get isolation level in current session?

Tags: informix, isolation-level

I set isolation level to dirty read some where, but I want to check current isolation level. How to get isolation level?
For DB2 found this: [How to obtain current isolation level on DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946986/how-to-obtain-current-isolation-level-on-db2),
but I'm looking for Informix 12.1. Can anybody help?

Comment: What driver / client are you using. Java JDBC provides a method to get the isolation level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your driver provides a method, I don't think there's a way other than querying appropriate tables in the `sysmaster` database.  The key information is in a table `sysopendb` (and also in another — `syssqlstat` which is not readable by the general public: SQL -272: No SELECT permission for syssqlstat).

File: `find.isolation.sql`

```
SELECT s.sid,
       s.username,
       s.feprogram,
       o.odb_dbname,
       o.odb_isolation,
  FROM syssessions AS s
  JOIN sysopendb AS o ON s.sid = o.odb_sessionid
 WHERE s.sid = DBINFO('sessionid')
```

The `syssessions` and `sysopendb` tables are generally readable.  You could simply query `sysopendb` and not use `syssessions` at all — and you could simply fetch the `odb_isolation` column.   The other information assures me I got the right information.

The statements that alter isolation level are:

- [SET ISOLATION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-set-isolation-statement)
- [SET TRANSACTION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-set-transaction-statement)

SET ISOLATION can be used outside a transaction (it is an Informix extension, but also the one most commonly used by Informix users).  SET TRANSACTION can only be used while a transaction is running.

The other key information is decoding the isolation level.  I used this script running as user `informix`:

```sh
for level in "read committed" "repeatable read" "serializable" "read uncommitted"
do
    sqlcmd -d sysmaster \
        -e begin \
        -x \
        -e "set transaction isolation level $level" \
        -e 'trace off' \
        -f find.isolation.sql
done

for level in "dirty read" "committed read" "committed read last committed" \
             "repeatable read" "cursor stability"
do
    a6 sqlcmd -d sysmaster -x \
        -e "set isolation to $level" \
        -e 'trace off' \
        -f find.isolation.sql
done
```

The output was:

```sql
+ set transaction isolation level read committed
479|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|2
+ set transaction isolation level repeatable read
480|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|5
+ set transaction isolation level serializable
481|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|5
+ set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
482|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|1
+ set isolation to dirty read
483|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|1
+ set isolation to committed read
484|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|2
+ set isolation to committed read last committed
485|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|11
+ set isolation to repeatable read
486|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|5
+ set isolation to cursor stability
487|informix|/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/sqlcmd|sysmaster|3
```

I used this query and the results to find `syssqlstat` and other tables with a column name containing `iso`:

```sh
$ sqlcmd -d sysmaster -e "select t.tabname, t.tabid, t.tabtype, c.colname,
>                                c.colno, c.coltype, c.collength
>                           from systables as t
>                           join syscolumns as c on t.tabid = c.tabid
>                           where c.colname matches '*iso*'"
systxptab|116|T|isolevel|25|1|2
sysxatab|117|T|isolevel|5|1|2
sysopendb|181|T|odb_isolation|7|1|2
syssqlstat|183|T|sqs_iso|3|1|2
syssqltrace|218|T|sql_isollevel|37|2|4
systrans|277|V|tx_isolevel|15|1|2
syssqlcurall|286|V|sqc_isolationlevel|3|13|200
syssqlcurses|287|V|scs_isolationlevel|3|13|200
$
```

The program in use is SQLCMD (available from the [IIUG Software
Archive](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)), which
I wrote to behave consistently in shell scripting contexts whereas
DB-Access doesn't.
It dates back to 1986 (before there was `dbaccess`; in those days, you
used `isql` instead — DB-Access was carved out of `isql` in an
evening).
It bears no relation to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the
same name — except for the name and having the same general purpose
(manipulate SQL databases).
You could more or less achieve the same result using DB-Access.